# Will I pay tax on selling the stock purchase plan I was granted by my employer in Germany?

Tags: taxes, stocks, tax-deduction, shares, germany

Let's say an employer offers an stock purchase plan of 100EUR contribution from NET monthly salary of the employee across a quarter, that will be 300EUR total.

Now let's say the employee at the end of the quarter decides to sell the shares and get back cash, assuming that the share price is THE SAME and haven't changed, this means that the shares are worth 300EUR.

My question is, will the employee get 300EUR back? Or will those be taxed before the employee gets them?

Further extending the situation, what happens in case of profit and loss? Please note that I'm not taking into consideration any grants at all.

Thanks for helping.

Comment: What country is this?  Options, and option tax arrangements, are really diverse.  BTW do you really mean "options" on shares or in this scheme do you get shares as such?

Comment: This sounds similar to an employee stock purchase plan (ESPP) in the US. Here, you only pay taxes on any discounts on the purchase price, or capital gains on the shares, but otherwise you just "get back" what you put in. I can't speak for Germany though.

Comment: It is Germany, I've updated the question title. Regarding what I mean by options, it's basically similar to the employee stock purchase plan Dan A. has mentioned.

Comment: At the end of the quarter, are you able to buy the shares at a discounted price, or do you pay whatever the current share price is?

Comment: Each month, a deduction is made out of my net salary, which is used to buy stocks at whatever price it is at that particular moment. At the end of a quarter, I can opt out and withdraw my money.

Comment: Since the deduction is made from your net salary, you have already paid taxes on that money, so I would guess it's similar to the US where if you opt out (or sell the shares immediately for no gain), you simply get your money back with no additional tax owed. Thanks for the clarification - now we wait for an expert in German tax law to come along :)

Comment: Thanks a lot Dan for the answer, I thought the same too, until I read about "Capital Gain Tax", it mentioned that since this is a trace, then it's taxed, which made me super confused and eventually posted this question.

Comment: Is this "Betriebliche Altersvorsorge"? If so, most companies in Germany handle these through contracts with banks or insurances, You have to tax the cash they pay out in retirement, but whether you can sell/cash out the stocks that easily (not to my knowledge) before retirement depends heavily on the specific contract. More information would be needed if that is the case. See e.g. here for more information yourself: https://www.finanztip.de/betriebliche-altersvorsorge/

Comment: @Kareem , I believe there is no connection at all to "options" (which are quite different from stock).  I am going to remove mentions of "options" from the question.  (You naturally can and should edit as you wish!)

Comment: @R.K. But the Betriebliche Altersvorsorge gets deducted from the gross salary. (That's easy to miss however: I get it deducted from the gross, added to the net and then subtracted from the net again, or something like this.)

Comment: @glglgl Oh, you're right. This mentions NET. Now I'm confused what the benefit for the employee (or frankly, the employer) is in the mentioned stock purchase plan. If it doesn't fall under BaV or any other scheme like Riester it should get taxed, excluding the "Freibetrag".

Comment: @Fattie Please feel free to edit the question, I don't mind at all, I'm grateful for the corrections :)
I can see that I now own "shares" worth the money I mentioned in the question, they label it as "Option Plan" however, I guess they mean an "option plan" to buy company "shares".

Comment: @R.K. I don't think this is "Betriebliche Altersvorsorge", it's company shares. I am also very confused how me as an employee will benefit from this, that's why I asked this question. I'm also new to the whole thing so it's quite confusing for me.

Comment: @Kareem Ah ok. I would guess you'd have to pay the 25% "Abgeltungssteuer" (+ "Solidaritaetszuschlag" + possibly church tax) on profits. The first 801€ (or 1600€ for couples) would be free on your total gains for a year. If there would be no profits you might not have to tax it, if there are losses you could total it with other possible gains to reduce the overall taxload. Since it's a deduction from your net, it seems like something you could opt out (check your contract / ask HR). It may be benefitial for you if you can buy stocks for a reduced price (or additional cash from your employer).